# Find maximum number of valid combinations for elements of two arrays

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

There are two n-length arrays ( `a` and `b` ) consisting of integers > 2.

On every turn I want to remove an integer from each array ( `a[i]` and `b[j]` )  given that a certain condition about them is true (e.g. that they are not co-prime). ( If the condition is not true, I'll try to remove another combination )

After all I want to find the maximum number of turns I can achieve this (until there is no possible combination to remove which meets the condition). Let's call this the optimum number of turns.

I tried to solve this with a search algorithm and a `PriorityQueue` using Python:

```
def search(n, a, b):
    q = queue.PriorityQueue()
    encountered = set()
    encountered.add((tuple(a), tuple(b)))
    q.put((number_of_coprime_combinations(a, b), a, b))

    while q:
        cost, a, b = q.get()
        combs = not_coprime_combinations(a, b)

        if not combs:
            return n - len(a)

        for a, b in combs:
            if not (tuple(a), tuple(b)) in encountered:
                q.put((number_of_coprime_combinations(a, b), a, b))
                encountered.add((tuple(a), tuple(b)))
```

`number_of_coprime_combinations(a, b)` returns the number of possible co-prime combinations given the arrays `a` and `b`. This is used as the cost of the given state of the two arrays.

```
def number_of_coprime_combinations(a, b):
    n = 0

    for idx_a, x in enumerate(a):
        for idx_b, y in enumerate(b):
            if is_coprime(x, y):
                n += 1

    return n
```

`not_coprime_combinations(a, b)` returns a list of possible states, where a not co-prime combination has been removed from `a` and `b`:

```
def not_coprime_combinations(a, b):
    l = []

    for idx_a, x in enumerate(a):
        for idx_b, y in enumerate(b):
            if not is_coprime(x, y):
                u, v = a[:], b[:]
                del(u[idx_a])
                del(v[idx_b])
                l.append((u, v))

    return l

>>> not_coprime_combinations([2,3],[5,6])
[([3], [5]), ([2], [5])]
```

The problem is that this solution is highly inefficient for large arrays of large integers. So I'm wondering if there is any better solution to this problem..

**EXAMPLE:**

```
n = 4
a = [2, 5, 6, 7] 
b = [4, 9, 10, 12]
```

One could remove:

```
(2, 4)
(5, 10)
(6, 9)
```

Which would lead to the optimum solution:

```
a = [7]
b = [12]
```

But if one would remove:

```
(6, 12)
(2, 10)
```

one would get to the suboptimal solution:

```
a = [5, 7]
b = [4, 9]
```

The algorithm should always come up the optimum number of turns (in this example 3).

Comment: Please include the code for the functions `number_of_coprime_combinations` and `not_coprime_combinations` . Also - provide a sample set of data and what the "result" should be.

Comment: [Maximum matchings in bipartite graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat thx, I'll let you know whether that works

Comment: question from ongoing contest on hackerrank...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, to solve this:

- Construct bipartite graph G such that for each Ai and Bj, if GCD(Ai,Bj) > 1, there is an edge (Ai, Bj) in G.
- Find the **maximum matching** of G
- Cardinality of the matching is the solution

I don't see how this could be solved faster.

Comment: thx, I have to read about those graphs. I'll let you know if it works for me ;)!

Answer (score 1):

I know where this problem you took.
And you solution for this problem is wrong because its O(n^2) and greedy.  n <= 10^5. 2 > a,b < 10^9 from array

I think in this problem you have to find some trick. And all algorithm for maximum matchings in bipartite graphs will TL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. Function `is_coprime_pair(pair)` is defined, accepts a list of length 2 and returns `True`
   for a pair of prime numbers
2. `a` and `b` are iterables to combine

```
    import itertools  
    not_coprimes = itertools.filterfalse(is_coprime_pair, itertools.product(a, b))
```

`not_coprimes` will hold all pairs that don't contain two prime numbers

Comment: Sry, the question was somewhat unclear. It's not the `not_coprime_combinations` function I'm trying to optimize but the whole alogrithm ;)  
Furthermore not_coprime_combinations should return a list of states where a not-coprime combination of numbers has been removed. (A state is a combination of array `a` and `b`).  
So for example:

    `>>> not_coprime_combinations([2,5,6],[4,9,10])` should return  
    `[([5, 6], [9, 10]), ([5, 6], [4, 9]), ([2, 6], [4, 9]), ([2, 5], [9, 10]), ([2, 5], [4, 10]), ([2, 5], [4, 9])]`